# Improving Performance When Loading Styles (e.g. styles.css)

Tags: performance, css, menu, styles

How to avoid loading times so that the user doesn't see two different styles? This can be observe during the first two seconds of loading.

Please refer to the following screenshot,
[Compare the Search Menus](http://www.flickr.com/photos/118326936@N06/12805650924/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would set the menu CSS to `#menu select {visibility:hidden;}` initially, and then change back to `visibility:visible;` on page load -- using Javascript or jQuery, or at the end of the CSS style sheet.

```
// Change menu select styles on load with jQuery
$(function() {
  $('#menu select').css('visiblity', visible');
});
```

or

```
<script>
  // Plain javascript hiding an entire menu div group
  document.getElementById('menu-container').style.visibility = "visible";
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I will try this!!! :) Which of the 3 options is more efficient: Javascript, jQuery, or at the end of the CSS style sheet?

Comment: Do you already have jQuery served with your page? If so I would use that, if not then use plain Javascript.
[See this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bradleyflood/THMM7/)

Comment: Thanks again!!! I have jQuery served in my WP Site. Do I add this function to functions.php? Do I have to call this function too?

Comment: @Ignacio You could include the `<script>` in your footer.php file before the closing `</body>` tag, or place this in one of your included Javascript files that (located in your themes folder in wp-content)

Answer (score -1):

[Put CSS at the bottom](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-bottom.php) will make your webpage "white" for until all the style sheet is loaded.

> This causes the blank white screen problem. The page is totally blank
>   until the stylesheet at the bottom is downloaded, on the order of 6-10
>   seconds for this page. The browser is waiting for the stylesheet to be
>   loaded before it renders anything else in the page, even the static
>   text.

Compare with [Put CSS at the top](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/css-top.php)

(from [High Performance Websites - Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/hpws/))

Comment: I am actually using an external style sheet. Does this rule applies? Thanks

Comment: I try to add these style in a Child Theme, to test if loading time could be improved. However, this seems to make no difference... Load time remains the same. Any other ideas? Thanks!

Comment: In case your webpage have too many dynamic elements and scripts, I prefer using javascript to do the job. For example you can show a loading overlay over the page for until the page is loaded, and put that script at the top of your <body> tag. Here is a example: http://dinhquangtrung.net/ - you will see a black screen with text for until all the image is loaded.